# Grails - Won't open localhost when adding data to bootstrap.groovy

Tags: grails

I am trying to learn Grails and following along the guide on grails.org http://guides.grails.org/creating-your-first-grails-app/guide/index.html which to some extend works fine. My issue is, that I follow the guide to the dot, and when I come to part 4.4 about bootstrapping data. I fill in the code in the BootStrap.groovy file in the init folder.

When I then proceed to run my app and try to connec to the url localhost:8080 the site simply will not load. I can acces the dbconsole and see that the data is bootstrapped, so I guess the app is working to some extend. But the site wont load.

When I remove 2 of the Vehicles, the site loads fine. I have tried using grails-clean, and kill all processes on the port 8080, stille nothing helps.

Please help me with this, as I am stuck!

Answer (score 2):

In your save method call, add `failOnError: true`. It's likely that something is failing when you try to save it. Also keep an eye on your console for error messages.

If that doesn't help, post some exact code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I just ran the command: grails clean, and it worked fine afterwards.